# Building a pipline structure using c ++ threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have three algorithms that I would like to process in a kind of pipline. All algorithms are to be executed endlessly, with continuous new data.
The algorithm A creates a data set from a sensor
algorithm B and C use this data set to derive events from it (B and C are independent of each other).
However, all three algorithms take different lengths of time.

```
|AAAA AAAA AAAA AAAA
|     BBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBBB
|     C    C    C    C
--------------------------- 
                          time
```

it is clear to me that algorithm B does not get every value of A and therefore only processes every second one sometimes. But that's not bad...

My idea would be something like this:

```
std::thread A_Thread;
std::thread B_Thread;
std::thread C_Thread;

while(true)
{
    if (!A_Thread.joinable())
    {
        A_Thread = std::thread(&A::a, this);                
    }

    if (!B_Thread.joinable())
    {
        B_Thread = std::thread(&B::b, this);                
    }

    if (!C_Thread.joinable())
    {
        C_Thread = std::thread(&C::c, this);                
    }
}
```

My idea is: I check in an endless loop whether the thread is still working, if not I restart it.
Within the individual threads I use a timestamp to check whether the currently available data has already been processed. A, B and C are methods that are located in the instance in which the threads are called. **I guess I misunderstood joinable**, because the threads unfortunately do not end themselves. So my first question would be how can I check if a thread grade is still working?
I thought a thread ended itself when it reached the last one, but apparently not. Do I need a join for this? But then my endless loop no longer works ...

Another question is the variable exchange.
i use instances within the threads where i save the results. the instance is in the instance (this) that calls the thread. is this possible?
It only ever writes one thread to a variable, but everyone should be able to read.

is the approach reasonable or grossly negligent?

Comment: Generally you should try to reuse the same threads as much as possible because it is very expensive to create them.

Comment: Whether threads "do not end themselves" or not has absolutely nothing to do, whatsoever with the parent thread joining them. If your threads never end it must be a bug in their code that you will have to find and fix. Obviously noone here can help you with that based on the code that's (not) shown here.

Comment: I highly suggest using some thread pool library and schedule tasks in them. Doing it manually like this is not only error prone but also very slow and verbose

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you invert the problem: have thread A notify threads B and C whenever there is new data available, and have threads B and C wait for this data.

```
// Shared variables for all three threads
std::shared_ptr<sensor_data> content;
std::condition_variable content_cv;
std::mutex content_mutex;

void thread_A() {
    while (true) { 
        shared_ptr<sensor_data> local_data = generate_sensor_data();
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(content_mutex);
        // Replace content with fresh sensor data and notify threads.
        std::swap(local_data, content);
        content_cv.notify_all();
    }
}

void thread_B() { // Same for thread C
    int last_seen = 0;
    while (true) {
        shared_ptr<sensor_data> local_content;
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(content_mutex);
            content_cv.wait(lock, []() { return content && content->version > last_seen; });
            local_content = content;
            last_seen = local_content->version;
        }
        // Do something with local_content
    }
}
```

Note that there is a slight possibility that thread B and C encounter a "spurious wakeup", ie the condition variable will wake up without thread A signaling. This is countered by keeping track of `content->version` and only proceeding if a higher version is seen. You could use timestamps as well, of course.

Comment: This is tidy, but I'm not sure it's optimal. If B takes longer than A, thread C is sitting around doing nothing to help catch up with A.

Comment: OP states that they are okay with thread B not seeing every datapoint produced by A. Otherwise I would have suggested a task pool, as others have.

Comment: Fair comment - thank you for taking the time to come back to me.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should use task-based parallelism when you specify tasks and dependencies between them and let the system execute them in parallel. This is what [Intel TBB Task Scheduler](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506294) does for you.